# How to get status of Azure durable functions when the function app is linked to a static web application?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-durable-functions, azure-static-web-app

I have Azure durable functions app which is linked to a Azure static web app.
I'm able to orchestrate function app through http trigger but I'm unable to access status url `statusQueryGetUri`
I'm getting following error,
`{"code":400,"message":"Login not supported for provider azureStaticWebApps"}`

How can I access status of durable function? do I have to write another HTTPTrigger GET function?

Answer (score 1):

As of now you can check the `statusQueryGetUri` is through HTTP endpoints. `statusQueryGetUri`always requires a System Key as it is an admin endpoint.

```
GET <rootUrl>/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/<GUID>
?taskHub={taskHub}
&connection={connection}
&code={systemKey}
```

You can also use this key to set the `x-functions-key` header of the http request.

**REFERENCES:**
[HTTP API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-http-api).

[How to check running status and stop Durable function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55982540/how-to-check-running-status-and-stop-durable-function)