# how to get azure durable Functions activity status inside the Orchestrator function?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-powershell, azure-durable-functions

I have below code For
Orchestrator Function
**run.ps1**

```
param($Context)
$output = @()
$input="test"
$output1 = Invoke-DurableActivity -FunctionName 'storage_account' -Input $input -nowait
Wait-ActivityFunction -Task $output1
$output1
```

function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "Context",
      "type": "orchestrationTrigger",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

Activity Trigger -- storage_account
**function.json**

```
 {
      "bindings": [
        {
          "name": "name",
          "type": "activityTrigger",
          "direction": "in"
        }
      ]
    }
```

**run.ps1**

```
param($name)
$rg="test"
$location="westus"
$checkname = (Get-AzStorageAccountNameAvailability $name).NameAvailable

If($checkname -eq "False"){
$name= $name + "date"+(get-date -Format MMdd)+"time"+(get-date -Format hhmm)
}
 "Storage Account $name :inprogress"
$accountstatus = New-AzStorageAccount -Name $name -ResourceGroupName $rg -SkuName Standard_LRS -Location $location 
IF(($accountstatus.ProvisioningState) -eq 'Succeeded'){
    "Storage Account $name :Created"
}
```

Is there any ways to get  durable Functions activity status inside the **statusQueryGetUri** or inside the Orchestrator ?
Currently result will be getting after all completed but I need the result for every activity like creating or created. I can set single status using

**Update:**
I can get single status using (docs:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-custom-orchestration-status?tabs=powershell#querying-custom-status-with-http Set-DurableCustomStatus) there is only single status can be store , If I use customstatus 2 times then 2nd one (or last one show on output) will be show in output & 1st one will be disappear. but I'm looking for the status like

```
{
  "customStatus": ["Completed", "Completed", "Started", "Started", "Completed"]
}
```

docs:https://joonasw.net/view/track-activity-and-sub-orchestrator-progress-in-azure-durable-functions-orchestrators

multiple status achieved by C# but I cannot see any docs for multiple custom status cannot be set by powershell.

Comment: Not sure about ps but in C# I know the status of the orchestrator by setting a custom status before each function app call using IDurableOrchestrationContext.SetCustomStatus("some status") then serving it in another function with an HttpTrigger using IDurableOrchestrationClient.GetStatusAsync()

Comment: I'm not familiar with Azure Functions, but if I understand you correctly, you want to _iteratively add to_ custom status information already associated with a function. Assuming there are no concurrency issues, couldn't you first _get_ the current info, modify it, and then re-upload?

Answer (score 0):

how to get azure durable Functions activity status inside the Orchestrator function?

> Is there any ways to get durable Functions activity status inside the **statusQueryGetUri** or inside the Orchestrator?

**statusQueryGetUri** requires the Http Endpoint of the Functions activity class which also requires the system key as admin endpoint. Because status endpoint URL contains the same value as the **[statusQueryGetUri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-http-api#response)** field.

Even the custom status can be set using PowerShell code to durable activity functions, the status can be queried using the HTTP [GET API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-custom-orchestration-status?tabs=powershell#querying-custom-status-with-http) Request.

Refer to [Marc’s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56005499) Answer on getting the activity function status using the Http Endpoints and also Azure Functions Core Tools Cmdlet.

Comment: @sevanesan, you're right we can set custom status as per docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-custom-orchestration-status?tabs=powershell#querying-custom-status-with-http) but there is only single status can be store , If I use customstatus 2 times then 2nd one will be show in output. you can see the docs (https://joonasw.net/view/track-activity-and-sub-orchestrator-progress-in-azure-durable-functions-orchestrators) that have multiple "customStatus": ["Completed", "Completed", "Started", "Started", "Completed"] found, I'm exactly looking for.